# Im inserting data with php code but its not working and give( un defined index:name)at submit page

Tags: php

I am getting this error:

> undefined index:name
>   why its not responding.

```
<?php
$url="localhost";
$user="root";
$password="";
$db="sms";
$connection=new mysqli($url,$user,$password,$db);
$username=$_POST["name"];
$query="INSERT INTO student(name)VALUES('".$username."')";
$connection->query($query);   
?>
```

Comment: What does your `student` table look like? The error message indicates the `name` column doesnt exist

Answer (score 0):

When you get Username `$username = $_POST["name"];` Value for $username variable come from global $_POST variable. If you start your script without POST, you cant read key 'name' from $_POST array. This key didn't exist and you get this error. SOLUTION for this problem. Just check for $_POST value with isset() and if() statments.

```
if (isset($_POST["name"])) {
    $username=$_POST["name"];
    $query="INSERT INTO student(name)VALUES('".$username."')";
    $connection->query($query);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `<input type="blablabla" name="name" ...>`

Also make sure to wrap the PHP code in:

```
if(!empty($_POST["name"])){
    // the code you posted ...
}
```

Comment: <form action="submit.php" method="POST">
 <tr><td><input type="text" name="name"><input type="submit" ></td></tr>
</form>

Comment: this is html code

Comment: Muhammad, ok. Then make sure to wrap your code in the if condition